# Insignificant p-value for Alpha when estimating GJR-GARCH

Tags: estimation, garch, volatility-forecasting

I am using E-views and estimating GJR-GARCH (i.e. GARCH(1,1) with a Threshold Order of 1). The data in question is Daily returns for the ASX200 index. I am only using a constant in my my mean equation with no ARMA terms.

The formula E-views uses is as below.

GARCH = C(2) + C(3)*RESID(-1)^2 + C(4)*RESID(-1)^2*(RESID(-1)<0) +
        C(5)*GARCH(-1)

The output yields a very high p-value for RESID(-1)^2. It yields 0.8900 to be exact. What could be the cause for this and is there a reason to worry, or a way to correct it?

EDIT: Have included the equation output, and the estimation command given in E-views
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could add a picture with the output? (It is not strictly necessary, but maybe there is something interesting to find.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Have edited with the pictures added.

Comment: @RichardHardy Any thoughts Richard? I've read an interpretation elsewhere, unsure how correct. Basically the asymmetry term (3rd term in the variance equation) is positve and highly significant indicating an asymmetry effect. However, Resid(-1)^2 (or Alpha) is insignificant because positive shocks have no effect on the performance of the index. And this positive effect is measured by Alpha, hence why the coefficient is negative and so low. Basically, the coefficient and p-value are working together. Conclusion: bad news has a greater effect on volatility than good news (Alpha + Asymmetry term)

Comment: That sounds more or less right. Note that you have $u_{t-1}^2$ and $u_{t-1}^2\times I(u_{t-1}<0)$ rather than $u_{t-1}^2\times I(u_{t-1}>0)$ and $u_{t-1}^2\times I(u_{t-1}<0)$, and the two are not the same.

Comment: Could  you kindly elbaorate on your last comment, please. What are the implications? I have simply computed the output as per the software and Brooks Introductory Econometrics.

Comment: I will not go through this in detail (as I do not know the answer by heart; but it should be fairly easy to derive), but I wanted to point out that your interpretation sounds as if you had a model of the second kind above (with two indicators) but the actual model is really of the first kind (with just one indicator). This might sound a little sloppy, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. This may be a software/textbook issue. According to Brooks the above steps and output are for GJR. But I've seen contradictory info elsewhere that the output is actually that of a TGARCH model. Apparently the conclusions and interpretation are almost the same. If what you say is correct about my interpretation being more in line with the 2 indicators model, would the interpretation be just as applicable for the 1 indicator model? What would be the difference. No need for a lot of detail, but a quick elaboration on the subtle difference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess different models call for different interpretation. I do not know an answer that would not go into detail, but as I said, it should be fairly easy to work out once you sit down and write down an example. This what is implied by one model and what is implied by the other for (a) a positive shock and (b) a negative shock.

Comment: When you think about it, is it a bit like in seasonal modelling: if you have four seasons, you may either include an intercept plus three dummies or four dummies without the intercept. In the first case, the dummies show the difference from the omitted period (the one that does not have a dummy); while in the second case, the dummies show overall levels for each period (not relative to other periods).

Comment: @RichardHardy Hope its ok to revisit this Richard, happy to continue in chat if its not appropriate here. Not sure how to start one though. I did a lot more reading, it seems my question is exactly the following https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25028/how-to-deal-with-negative-arch-terms. As Eviews can't impose bounds, I am left with a model where Alpha1 must be >0, as its one of the non-negativity constraints. But this is not the case, and the value is also insignificant. I'm not sure how I should write it though, should I just acknowledge the shortcoming is due to the software?

Comment: Is the model stille even valid I guess would be my main question. Thanks. And apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry for a late response. I read your comment earlier but did not have a quick answer. Unfortunately, I am still having a busy time... My initial thoughts are: by pointing out the problem you show that you understand it, which is good. Ideally you would fix it, but if the software does not allow to do that easily, then maybe you can leave it. If your fitted volatility is far into the positive territory, then you would not have big problems with $\alpha_1<0$. You could even estimate the size of the shock that would bring the estimated variance into the negative and tell how likely that is.

Comment: @RichardHardy It's no problem. I've submitted the paper already so it's done now. This was a totally new area for me and a lot of stuff I had to self teach myself as I'd not done any modules on this. But I really wanted to come back and thank you for all your help. Truly. I don't think I could have done it without the assistance of yourself and others on here. So thanks a lot. Have a great day!

Comment: you are welcome! Such thoughtful and kind feedback is rare, and it really matters! After all, there is more than reputation points and badges on this site. I have answered many unpopular questions with low views and no votes (actually, I feel that most of my answers are to such questions), and the main reward was the feeling that I was helping a fellow student. I am very, very glad to hear you found my input helpful, and I wish you best of luck in your statistical endeavours :)